# How to get sub query columns in main query with WHERE EXISTS in PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pg

I am stuck with a query which takes more time in `JOIN`, I want to use `WHERE EXISTS` in place of `JOIN` since as performance wise `EXISTS` takes less time than it.

I have modified the query and it's executing as per expectation but I am not able to use `sub query's columns` in my main query

Here is my `query`

```
SELECT MAX(st.grade_level::integer) AS grades ,
       scl.sid AS org_sourced_id
FROM schedules_53b055b75cd237fde3af904c1e726e12 sch
LEFT JOIN schools scl ON(sch.school_id=scl.school_id)
AND scl.batch_id=sch.batch_id
AND scl.client_id = sch.client_id
AND sch.run_id = scl.run_id
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT t.term_id,t.abbreviation
     FROM terms t
     WHERE (sch.term = t.term_id)
       AND t.batch_id=sch.batch_id
       AND t.client_id = sch.client_id
       AND t.run_id = sch.run_id)
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT st.grade_level,
            st.sid
     FROM students st
     WHERE (sch.student_id=st.sid)
       AND st.batch_id= sch.batch_id
       AND st.client_id = sch.client_id
       AND st.run_id = sch.run_id)
GROUP BY scl.sid ,
         sch.course_name ,
         sch.course_number,
         sch.school_id
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "st"
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 29
```

I have only used one column here just for sample but I have to use more fields from `sub query`.

My main aim is that how can I achieve this with `EXISTS` or any alternate solution which is more optimal as performance wise

I am using `pg` module on `Node.js` since as back end I am using `Node.js`.

**UPDATE**

Query with `JOIN`

```
SELECT MAX(st.grade_level::integer) AS grades ,
       scl.sid AS org_sourced_id
FROM schedules_53b055b75cd237fde3af904c1e726e12 sch
LEFT JOIN schools scl ON(sch.school_id=scl.school_id)
AND scl.batch_id=sch.batch_id
AND scl.client_id = sch.client_id
AND sch.run_id = scl.run_id
LEFT JOIN terms t ON (sch.term = t.term_id)
AND t.batch_id=sch.batch_id
AND t.client_id = sch.client_id
AND t.run_id = sch.run_id
LEFT JOIN students st ON (sch.student_id=st.sid)
AND st.batch_id= sch.batch_id
AND st.client_id = sch.client_id
AND st.run_id = sch.run_id
GROUP BY scl.sid ,
         sch.course_name ,
         sch.course_number,
         sch.school_id
```

Comment: `exists` returns a boolean not arbitrary values from the query. You will have to join the subquery.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto For performance wise is there any other options in place of `JOIN` since it's taking too much time for huge records?

Comment: Updated my question with `JOIN` query

Comment: `where exists` is functionally equivalent to an `inner join` not to an `outer left join` as in your query.

Comment: Do you have indexing on your column ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum I have created indexes on required column

Comment: @abdulbarik it would be better if you post your table structure of those four table as well. This will help us to understand it more better way.